# Issues updating MySQL table with dynamic data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working on a project where I am trying to insert values into a MySQL table. Before starting this project I verified that I had the necessary JAR file setup and tested the SQL connection. I thought I was on the right track, but I can't seem to get past these errors popping up in the console. I have a feeling I am not inserting data correctly into MySQL through Eclipse. I was hoping someone here may know of a better process or way of completing this. My source code is posted below. The file "theraven.txt" that is being read from is in the project directory.

```java
public class DatabaseGO {

    //private static Connection connection = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        FileInputStream findIt = new FileInputStream("theraven.txt");
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(findIt);    
        
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
    
            String nextWord = fileInput.next();
    
            if (words.contains(nextWord)) {
                int index = words.indexOf(nextWord);
                count.set(index,  count.get(index)+ 1);
            }
            else {
                words.add(nextWord);
                count.add(1);
            }
        }
        
        fileInput.close();
        findIt.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
            Collections.sort(count, Collections.reverseOrder());
        
        //////////////////////////////
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/word_occurrences";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "kittylitter";
        
        String sql = "INSERT INTO word(countNumber, `countName`) VALUES(?,?)";
        
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

                pst.setInt(1, count.get(i));
                pst.setString(2, words.get(i));
                pst.executeUpdate();
            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseGO.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } 
    }
    }
}
```

This is the current errors I am getting:

```
SEVERE: Unknown column 'countNumber' in 'field list'
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'countNumber' in 'field list'
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at database.DatabaseGO.main(DatabaseGO.java:67)

Nov 09, 2022 12:00:14 AM database.DatabaseGO main
```

In MySQL I have a table named word and three columns named `recordNumber` Int (set to auto-increment), `wordCount` Int, and `wordName` VARCHAR(45). I was hoping the program would output the count of the name next to the name.

Comment: If your table `word` has columns `recordNumber`, `wordCount` and `wordName`, why are you referencing column names `countNumber` and `countName`? As an aside, additions to your question should be done through editing your question, not by adding comments. I have copied your comment to the question this time, but in the future, please do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. The problem was with the naming convention in my program. When I inserted the correct column names, it worked. I was up late working on this project, I somehow missed this. Thank you and apologies for the misprint.

Answer (score 0):

The issue says that the table word doesn't have column countNumber.
Kindly recheck your table description.

Alternatively, an insert query can run without column names, try with `INSERT INTO word VALUES(?,?)`.

Comment: Don't use insert without column reference, that is a bad habit to get into.